# android videoview stuck image

Tags: android, android-videoview

i've got a simple videoview. I've made a stop button with:

```
myVideoView.stopPlayback();
```

but when it stops it keeps the last scene of the video in the videoview.

How can i reset the videoview after the video has been stopped?